# Monero coins locked after sending money

Tags: balance, wallet, transaction-unlock-time, unlocked-balance

My whole balance locked after sending money. I have read about monero locking balance on the internet.
Balance blocking is only monero blockchain feature or all cryptocurrencies? Bitcoin locks money too?
I want to ask about solutions.
What if I received one transaction 1000 XMR once and I want to send coins to several different wallets? Do I have to wait about 25 minutes between transactions?
Is there a way to make it more comfortable and faster?
Hooe for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New outputs are locked for 10 blocks (unless the sender selects more), which is about 20 minutes on average. If all your monero is in a single output, then sending it will lock your entire balance for that number of blocks. There are two ways to avoid having to wait when sending to multiple recipients:

- ensure your wallet is made up of several outputs, so only what you send gets locked
- send to several recipients in the same transaction

For the first case, you can send to yourself, ie:

> transfer MYADDRESS 10 MYADDRESS 10 MYADDRESS 10 MYADDRESS 10 MYADDRESS 10

This will send 50 monero to yourself, and you'll end up with 5 outputs of 10 monero each.

For the second case, something similar:

> transfer ADDRESS1 10 ADDRESS2 5 ADDRESS3 2

The change will still be locked for 10 blocks, but you've paid the three recipients already.